# Compare two columns in excel and find the differences with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to write a macro that compares two columns and tells me if something from the first column does not exist in the second.

```
A   B
1   55
23  68
55  97
68  58
97  90
    14
    25
```

So I need to take the values from A and check if they are present in B, if not it shopuld give back the value from A which was not found.
Can you please help me on that

Comment: How do you want the return?  In a list, one per cell, or one cell with all the values not found delineated with a `,`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need vba.

This formula will do what you are asking.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))/(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),B:B,0))),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Put it in the first cell of the desired output and copy down till it returns blanks.

[image]

Comment: how can I modify this formula so it works with text?